# New flag options to aid faster nonsense answer removal

Tags: feature-request, tags, flags, not-an-answer

As there have been a lot of "Not An Answer" flag discussions lately, and I have hit that same issue as well, I propose a fix to the issue.

My proposal is to split the "Not An Answer" flag, splitting its intended use and its perceived use, into the following:

- Does not remotely look like an answer.
- Does not answer this question.

(Obviously better wording is needed)

The "Does not remotely look like an answer" flag behaves exactly the same as a NAA flag, first hitting the VLQ queue and/or (not sure how it works) the moderators.

The interesting point comes with the "Does not answer this question" flag, I believe this flag should go into a specific tag queue. Take a question on [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), this answer should go into a queue that is intended only for a select group of people with knowledge of Java.

Currently I think the best select group of people would be the ones who have a gold badge in the tag, but I don't see any reasonable harm for allowing silver and bronze (eventually) as well into the queue.

I'd say the available options when reviewing that queue are "Does not answer this question (correct flag)" and "It does answer this question (incorrect flag)". I propose that we need **two*** gold badge holders to delete an answer once has been selected that it indeed does not answer the question.
 * Using two people here as deleting an answer *looks* irreversible for the outside, whereas closing a question does not look irreversible.

Here the options then also exist to come up with a weight system to incorporate the silver and bronze tag holders, numbers are tentative but it may be that a gold user counts 50% towards deleting an answer, silver 25% and bronze 12.5%.

I'm undecided about allowing moderators into the tag queues with extra powers, as some form of domain knowledge is required. Though I neither think we should ignore the extra powers of the moderator totally.

Finally, what does it solve? Currently there is no way to flag such answers (despite it happening) and all you can do is downvote and leave a command to the answered, with as *optional* action to notify a chatroom about it, but really, they neither want to be spammed with such requests.

I believe this solution will help tremendously in cleaning up nonsense (from tag point of view) answers and will help reduce the number of flags moderators receive. The only resource on stakes here is precious coding time from SE.

Comment: Sounds very complex for not much gain. Downvotes already classify the content, and 20k+ users can vote to delete negatively scored answers already.

Comment: @Mat And how would you find such answers? I may find one and downvote it once... and then? Assume the question is not around with recent activity (which is fairly common), then nothing will happen and the bad answer will remain, possibly even on 0 score (if someone mindlessly upvoted).

Comment: Let's just change the wording of the flag to "Needs to be deleted".

Comment: *"Does not answer this question"* is quite subjective and should be down voted rather than flagged.

Comment: @slugster I believe gold badge holders pass the point of subjectiveness. And perhaps my wording is still off, but I mean the real answers that do not even attempt to answer the question and are basically incorrect nonsense.

Comment: when the content of an answer is wrong it's still an answer. All you can do is just downvote it to indicate that it's wrong.

Comment: @mehow Which is what I propose to fix... Simply downvoting is not dealing with the issue, it may even go unnoticed for months if nobody else cares. While on one hand few people would see the incorrect answer, on the other hand the whole meaning of stackoverflow is to provide a database of questions and answers and I suppose incorrect answers do not belong in there.

Comment: @skiwi convince me that downvoting wrong content is bad in first place. Why isnt a downvote on a bad answer enough to indicate that it's wrong? -3 downvotes gray out the answer anyway

Comment: @mehow It is not bad, in contrary it is good, however it will not ensure that the issue (the incorrect answer) will be dealt with. Nothing guarantees that within a reasonable amount of time the answer will be deleted.

Comment: @skiwi it does not have to be deleted. That's what voting is for - reward good stuff and downvote crap. The bad answers (which are still attempts at answering) are also good to have because you can leave a comment explaining what is wrong with the answer which I find educative in most cases

Comment: @mehow Perhaps we differ then in opinions. Whenever I see an obviously incorrect answer I want "to vaporize it", while others may be happy once they've done a single downvote to it even though it sticks around for weeks.

Comment: @skiwi yeah I noticed but I think I have got a good point here by keeping bad answers with comments explaining what is wrong. Any future visitor may benefit from it by understanding why a given answer is not correct. (obviously it can't be spam and non-sense answer)

Comment: "Does not answer this question" is never a reason to flag for removal. You may as well simply propose to rename the NAA flag instead.

Comment: @BoltClock Can you please eloborate on that? (In an answer for example) Youur comment seems quite edgy and I'd like to understand the thought process behind it. Would for example a similar idea but one that automatically puts downvoted answers in a queue (has quite a lot of tricky edge cases which *all* need to be solved) make more sense?

Comment: You might want to elaborate on what that specific reasoning means. As I interpret it, it means answers that, while they appear to be an attempt at addressing the question, miss the point of the question completely (e.g. answering a "why?" question with "here's the solution"). That is not grounds for deleting an answer, only for downvoting it.

Comment: @BoltClock It is quite subtle perhaps, but anything that is more or less a half-answer should stay but be downvoted on a per case basis. I attempt to address the answers that are obviously incorrect, examples would be http://stackoverflow.com/a/23748800/2057294 and most obviously http://stackoverflow.com/a/21864471/2057294. The first edges somewhere between debatable and up for blatant deletion, the second one opts in for blatant deletion in my opinion. I do by no means encourage deleting all downvoted answers, though I understand that it is a concern with such a system.

Answer (score 5):

Posted as CW to encourage people to extend/complete this.

There is a matrix of answer quality, and user reputation, and what are appropriate responses for non-moderators

Key:

> ```
> +1    => upvote             
> -1    => downvote
> -     => do nothing         
> Edit  => Improve the answer (and then perhaps +1)
> SE    => Suggest Edit       (and then perhaps +1 when approved)
> C     => Comment
> VD    => Vote-To-Delete
> NAA   => Flag as not-an-answer
> ```

Ranking the answer quality .... "junk" means there is no way to edit/fix the answer at all. It is not salvageable.

The table below...

```
   User Reputation (privilege)

                 >15     >50      >125      >2000 >20000
                 UpVote  Comment  VoteDown  Edit  Trusted

Answer
Quality
       High      +1      +1       +1       +1      +1     

       Medium    SE?     SE?      SE?      Edit?   Edit?

       Low       SE      SE/C     SE/C/-1  E/C/-1  E/C/-1

       Junk      NAA     NAA/C    -1/C     -1/C    VD/-1/C

       Spam/     Flag    Flag     Flag     Flag    Flag   <- Do not edit
       Offen.
```

The basic premise is:

- upvote what's good.
- improve what's not
- downvote if you can't/won't improve the answer (and comment if you feel that would be useful)
- enough DownVotes will add an answer to the Low-Quality review queue
- a vote-to-delete will add the answer to the Low-Quality queue
- flag only if you do not have access to the more appropriate tools.

Additionally, if you downvote, you lose a reputation point, but, at some point, with enough downvotes, the answer will be deleted, and you get your reputation back.

Comment: A few points that could/should be incorporated once someone wants to extend this post: 1) I don't think 20K users should be put much weight upon, as a lot of the users *encountering* these situations are not 20K. 2) How does the current system draw attention to answers that one downvotes?

Answer (score -1):

Another possibility is to *replace* the existing separation among choosing to upvote/downvote, closevote, and delete vote with a system of post ratings that would be associated with underlying operations. Here's how it could work:

> ```
> Rating                          => Automatic Actions
>
> Stupendously High Quality (SHQ) => upvote, add praise comment, award a bounty as applicable, automatically create Meta post to draw more attention to the answer
> Ultra High Quality (UHQ)        => upvote, add praise comment, award a bounty as applicable
> Very High Quality (VHQ)         => upvote, add praise comment
> High Quality (HQ)               => upvote
> Meh Quality (MQ)                => nothing
> Low Quality (LQ)                => downvote
> Very Low Quality (VLQ)          => downvote, raise flag, delete vote if user can
> Ultra Low Quality (ULQ)         => downvote, raise spam/rude flag, delete vote if user can
> Stupendously Low Quality (SLQ)  => downvote, raise spam/rude flag, delete vote if user can, automatically create Meta post to draw more attention to the answer
> ```

With this system, a user would not need to think (or remember) when they should downvote as opposed to flag, etc., but would just need to pick a quality level (maybe through a dropdown), and the system would automatically perform the associated actions. Of course, there could be a "manual override" function for experienced users that want to manually choose their voting/flagging behavior.

Comment: _"Automatic[ally]...add praise comment"_ Is there an automatic flag for removal of the useless comment, too?

Comment: Too hard to understand and to remember. Just have either a "thumps up" (works like SHQ) or a "thumps down" (works like SLQ). And since Stack Overflow is so rude to lazy people and bad content, how about having only the "thumps up" button?