# Why did a moderator decline my Not An Answer flag?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I flagged this answer as Not An Answer, but it was declined by a moderator:
[How can I configure my makefile for debug and release builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079832/how-can-i-configure-my-makefile-for-debug-and-release-builds/41153590#41153590)

I don't understand why it was declined...?

- It suggests making a change from `ifeq (DEBUG, 1)` to `ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1)`, which is not code that exists in the Question
- Therefore, it must refer to another answer, but there are many that use similar code, so it's not clear which one it was addressed at, considering edits
- Regardless, it should be a comment on that answer instead, and is not very useful (IMO) in its current state
- It is far from a complete answer that actually answers the question ([How can I configure my makefile for debug and release builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079832/how-can-i-configure-my-makefile-for-debug-and-release-builds))

Comment: Very confused why a 3k+ rep user edited it to give it code formatting and didn't think to flag it or anything else, and very confused that it has a +1

Comment: It's not an answer. It's not an attempt at answering either. I've come to this conclusion by looking at the question and some other answers. As far as I can tell, they only want the posts that can be classified as NAA by just looking at the post in that queue.

Comment: Congrats! You found an orange. [Guidance says that orange should be flagged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAUaw.png) but people claim that [technically it is an answer, despite being an orange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer#comment785820_225370)

Comment: *but the review guidelines clearly state that if you're unsure, hit "Skip".* The users who reviewed the post probably felt sure that a post saying, "Change `this code` to `that code`" is an answer. After all, NAA flags are only for posts that don't attempt to answer any question at all and "Change your code this way" definitely looks like it's trying to answer *something*.

Comment: @BSMP Fair. So what, it's a NAA that looks a whole lot like an Answer, and that's why my flag was declined? Someone didn't look close enough? Hah. I guess I just expected more effort from reviewers/moderators

Comment: @KeithM Yes, same story happened for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37296428/uiscrollview-keyboard-dismiss-interactively/37297110#37297110 and the answer from chat yesterday was "_if it looks like an Answer but is not answering the Question, then it's a job for 20k reputation users de delete, not for moderators_".

Comment: Related interesting Meta suggestions: [New flag options to aid faster nonsense answer removal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255515/new-flag-options-to-aid-faster-nonsense-answer-removal) and [Should “Very Low Quality” flags be offloaded entirely to tag experts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368875/should-very-low-quality-flags-be-offloaded-entirely-to-tag-experts)

Comment: @KeithM: NAA flags are designed to be hit-and-run click-through decisions for extremely obvious cases. The UI only shows the post in isolation. IOW: "looking close enough" and "spending more effort" isn't even possible. Think of it this way: Custom Flags are for decisions that require effort. That's why they have a comment field, so that the effort of a thorough investigation can be partially offloaded to you, and you can report and explain your findings. NAA and the other comment-less flags are for cases that are so obvious they need no explanation.

Comment: @JörgWMittag "The UI only shows the post in isolation" [citation-needed]

Comment: The answer appears to be deleted - can someone provide an image for those of us <10k?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The "not an answer" flag doesn't contain enough information to make it clear that the answer appears to have been intended for another question. It does still fit the site's definition of an answer, which is why the case for declining a NAA flag is strong.

For answers that appear to have been intended for a different question, or otherwise posted under this question by mistake, I recommend using a custom flag in the future for best results.

If the answer looks similar enough to the information given in the question that it could go either way (it's either an attempt to answer or not), however, I'd err on the side of caution and simply downvote it.

Comment: I thought the NAA flag includes flagging answers that should be comments instead. Have the rules changed?

Comment: @Keith M: An answer that suggests making a change in existing code is not a comment, even if the answer makes no effort to explain what the change does, why it works, etc. An example of a comment would be a request for clarification.

Comment: Well, I'd agree if the answer were suggesting a change to the Question Asker's code, but it's not. As it stands, there's no way to know what code the answer is referring to. I.e. suggestions for changes to answers should be comments on those answers, not separate answers. No?

Comment: The only exceptions I've seen are expanding existing answers with more than a phrase or sentence

Comment: @Keith M: When it's not clear what the answer is referring to, err on the side of caution and downvote, or raise a custom flag if it really bothers you and trust our judgement. You should only flag an answer as NAA when it's *clearly* NAA.

Comment: I *did* think it's clearly NAA :P Since comments regarding Answers should be Comments, not Answers

Comment: When I find an "answer" that really is a comment directed to another answer, I write a comment before flagging as NAA (e.g., *"This does not answer the question. This is a comment on USER's \[answer\](URL). To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below his post."*). @BoltClock Is this practice sufficient, or should I really raise custom mod flags?

Comment: @KeithM Alright how about: Only flag as NAA when it's _clearly_ NAA _without looking at any other post._ From the sounds of it, only by seeing the code wasn't in the question at all would an outside observer note that it must be commentary on another post, or posted to the wrong question.

Comment: @Kendra That doesn't make sense. How could you flag ANY answer as NAA if you can't look at the Question?

Comment: @KeithM Because some answers are just clearly not answers. For example, _"I like trains"_ is not an answer. A new question is not an answer. _"UserX is correct"_ with nothing else to it is not an answer. I don't remember for this _specific_ flag, but with a lot of flags, the mods get _just_ the post flagged and no context unless they specifically drill down for the context. So a mod seeing _just_ that answer and no context would think, _"That looks like an answer to me, however poor it might be."_ In most cases, if context is needed to see the flag is right, you should use the custom mod flag.

Comment: Then is there no flag for "This Answer should be a Comment?" Because I was fairly certain that fell under NAA, at least in the past. (I was under the impression mods could move answers to comments, or that even if they can't, such posts should be cleaned up.)

Comment: @KeithM There is. But if the post _looks like_ an answer to someone unfamiliar with the technology (We don't necessarily have a mod for each individual tech, after all.) your flag could easily be declined. If it's just a request for clarification, then yeah, it's a comment, clearly. But if it's _not_ super clear to others that it's a comment and not just an answer with a rhetorical question... Prepare for a potential declined flag.

Comment: It's my understanding that typically, flags such as the one I raised, which, like probably most other flags, are not immediately obvious to someone that doesn't know the tags, are only reviewed by users or moderators with experience in said tags -- who would be able to determine that the Answer doesn't answer the Question.

Comment: @KeithM There's nothing to limit who can see/act on a flag by tag experience. _Users_ can choose to filter certain review queues by tags, but they are not forced to. Mods can see/act on _every_ flag on the site. (I'll leave this be at this point- I'd hate to flood BoltClock with more notifications. Sorry, Bolt!)

Comment: @Kendra I know there's no *restriction* on it, but the review guidelines clearly state that if you're unsure, hit "Skip". Anyway, I'm still unclear if the definition of NAA has changed, or what? Still waiting on a clarification from BoltClock. Sure, it wasn't clear what the Answer in question was referring to, but it *WAS* clear that it was *NOT* referring to the Question, and I thought that was enough to flag NAA...

Comment: @KeithM The definition of NAA hasn't changed. Technically, NAA would be the correct flag. The issue is that the moderator interface _only_ shows the flagged post, not the question it's on, so if it looks like it could be an answer, the mod reviewing it is likely to decline the flag. If you use a custom flag, you can state that it's a nonsensical answer because it recommends _changing_ code that never existed, and the mod knows to take a closer look. NAA still means NAA; custom flags just make it more obvious that the answer is, in fact, NAA, so the mod is less likely to assume it's a bad flag.

Comment: @NicHartley "The issue is that the moderator interface only shows the flagged post, not the question it's on" [citation-needed] [*"“We cannot judge an answer that is flagged as "not an answer" when the only information that we see, that is, the answer alone as well as the question title” I don't get this. In the flag dashboard, all it takes is one click to show the question body, and I routinely do this when a NAA flag isn't immediately obvious."*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/156539)

Comment: @Braiam [Thanks for providing the citation you're looking for a few lines up from what you quoted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286229/a-minor-change-to-the-description-of-the-not-an-answer-flag-the-question-%E2%86%92/286270#comment156468_286270). It's apparently different on SO. Hell if I know _why_, but I'm not a mod. Oh, and also on the same page, [Shog9 explains why it's not always immediately obvious, even when you _really think_ it should be.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286366/1863564) Unless, of course, you think pseudocode should never be allowed in answers.

Comment: @NicHartley "this answer appears to address the asker's problem. Use downvotes to indicate inaccurate or entirely wrong answers. For subtle forms of abuse, choose "other" and explain the problem in detail." The text that Shog himself proposes to change the reject reason for moderators. Basically, he considers that moderators *should* remove answers that doesn't address the asker problem. BTW, ["If we don't have the full text displayed, we can click on the disclosure arrows to display the remainder of the answer and the first few lines of the question"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341841)

Comment: @Braiam Okay, that handles things that you think are obvious. You didn't address the fact that _they aren't always obvious_. Again, should pseudocode be allowed? If so, what about showing an algorithm in Python, rather than porting it to C#, even though that's what the question is in? Let's say someone asks about the 'best' sorting algorithm, in C# (and let's ignore the fact that it's a bad question -- it's just an example). Should something be deleted as NAA because they explain quicksort with Python, rather than C#? You might say it's a _bad_ answer, but that means DV, not delete as NAA.

Comment: For someone trying to process the sheer volume of flags that are raised on Stack Overflow, it's not always practical to read through the entire question and answer to see if, really, that answers the question or not, especially since it's not always involving tech you're familiar with. Whatever the interface, that will _always_ be true while SO is as big as it is now. It's safer to dispute or decline, and if you see a custom mod flag that gives an explanation which can be quickly and easily checked, then check it -- but otherwise, you assume good faith and act on that.

Comment: @NicHartley "they aren't always obvious" once you decide to activelly not to look for more information to decide in a non-obvious case, you inmediatelly lose your argument. Anyone handling a flag is *a reviewer*, and as reviewer you should be held with the highest amount of responsability, such as the responsability to inquire when something isn't obvoius *to you*. If moderators decide to act brain dead, who's going to actually apply some reasoning to the amount of power they have?

Comment: Maybe the option to type a short explanation regarding why a flag was picked would help situations like this? Something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yQH4.png

Comment: @Callum Watkins: I wonder how useful that will be if employed for flags like NAA that are reviewed by regular reviewers before being handed to the mods. As for the mods, I believe that would help with categorization as our UI does allow us to filter by flag type.

Comment: @BoltClock My idea was that, just like edits, the comment would give a window of insight into the thought process of the flagger at the time.

Comment: @Callum Watkins: Indeed. This insight will be useful to mods, and I can only hope that reviewers will appreciate the same insight (I personally have a hard time trusting reviewers in general).

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr**: the post is NAA, but the flag handling UI doesn't give enough context to determine that in this particular case.

There are two separate issues to consider here:

1. Is the post not-an-answer?
2. Is the not-an-answer flag the right one?

Nobody here is disputing that the post is not an answer to the question. It is, in fact, not even a comment to the question. It should, as you rightly pointed out, be a comment to the respective answer it is addressing.

However, the user interface for dealing with NAA flags is very restricted, in that it only shows the flagged post and nothing else. In your question and the comments, you describe why the post is not-an-answer: because the code it wants to correct doesn't even appear in the question and instead is code from another answer. Note that in order to come to the determination that the post is, in fact, NAA, you needed to examine *three* separate posts: the post in question, the question, and the other answer. None of the latter two are available to the person handling the NAA flag.

Thus, one should only use the NAA flag for posts that **cannot possibly be an answer to *any* imaginable question**. In other words: if you can construct a possible question to which this answer is an answer, then an NAA flag is not the right choice, because the person handling the flag has no way of knowing if this answer was posted as a response to exactly that hypothetical question or not.

The correct flag would be a custom mod flag with an explanation why this post is NAA.

Comment: While my answer mostly duplicates points already made in the other answer(s) as well as the comments, I felt it clarifies the important point that whether a post is NAA and whether an NAA flag is the right tool to communicate that fact, are two separate issues.

Comment: You just need to play [Jeopardy!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeopardy!) with the answer ...

Comment: "but the flag handling UI doesn't give enough context to determine that in this particular case." [citation-needed] [*"“We cannot judge an answer that is flagged as "not an answer" when the only information that we see, that is, the answer alone as well as the question title” I don't get this. In the flag dashboard, **all it takes is one click to show the question body**, and I routinely do this when a NAA flag isn't immediately obvious."*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/156539)